# How to format currency BRL(Brazil) in input fields?

Tags: sapui5

In my application I need to format number fields to BRL(Brazil) currency. This is my code:

```
                new sap.ui.layout.form.FormElement(this.createId('valor'),{
                label: 'Valor',
                fields: [
                    new sap.m.Input({
                         value:{
                            parts: [{
                                        path: '/valor'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        path: 'BRL'
                                    }
                                ],
                                type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency',
                                formatOptions: {
                                showMeasure: false
                                }
                            },
                        id: this.createId('txtValor')
                    }),
                ]
            }),
```

We suppose what my input value to be 1000.
The output it will be 1,000.00, but i need who the output to be 1.000,00

Do SAPUI5/OpenUI5 support currency BRL(Brazil)? I tried a lot, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The currency type uses the locale settings for formatting the output. I assume that in your case the format locale is not set to Brazilian Portugese and therefore the browser's locale is used.

You can set the format locale via:

```
sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().setFormatLocale("pt_BR");
```

Additionally you should also review your binding and change it to:

```
<Input id="valor" value="{path : '/valor', type : 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency'}"/>
```

[Here](https://jsbin.com/racewo/edit?html,output) you will find a small example. There is also an [example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.core.sample.TypeCurrency/preview) in the Explored application explaining the model data type.